# logistic regression or mantel-haenszel?

Tags: logistic, cochran-mantel-haenszel

For a 2x2xk table, where k are strata from repeated cross-sectional studies over the course of 10 years, would it be suitable with a Mantel-Haenszel test of common odds ratio or would a logistic regression analysis be more apropriate? The 2x2 part are purely nominal data.

Answer (score 2):

With large strata they should be identical. Only subtle differences arise between the two tests, [more discussion here](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~dipankar/bmtry711.11/lecture_15.pdf).

I would prefer the logistic regression model because it could be extended to use fixed or random effects to account for age / period / cohort effects of study follow-up.

Comment: The link given to more discussion is no longer usable, however, the author (Dipankar Bandyopadhyay, Ph.D.) reposted it at https://people.musc.edu/~bandyopd/bmtry711.11/lecture_15.pdf